# What is the difference between a Whiz deletion and using the present participle as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, present-participles, whiz-deletion

> The sleeping babies are adorable.

and

> The babies sleeping are adorable.

To me, the two sentences are identical in meaning. However, this doesn't seem to be the case in the following sentence:

> The singing sensation is a teen heart throb.

and

> The sensation singing is a teen heart throb.

To me, the subject of the first sentence is a singer whereas the subject of the second sentence is in the process of singing.

Is there a rule for when using a present participle as an adjective does not carry the same meaning as doing a whiz deletion?

Comment: _The singing sensation_ is an NP where the verb "singing" is modifying the noun "sensation" (i.e. it’s adjective-like), but _The sensation singing_, is a clause with “The singer” as subject and "singing" as verb. This is evident from the fact that it can be expanded into _The sensation singing Sinatra songs wonderfully at the Palais last night_ where "Sinatra songs" is direct object. Only verbs take objects. Same applies to your "babies" example, cf. the noun phrase _The sleeping babies_ and the clause _The babies sleeping peacefully in their cots_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your difficulty lies with the fact that *singing sensation* is a commonly used compound term, and therefore turning the phrase around has a different meaning. I couldn't find an online definition of "singing sensation", however a quick search will find many examples of its usage:

> [Singing sensation](http://6abc.com/archive/8727767/) Susan Boyle has been awarded an honorary doctorate
>   from a Scottish university.

There is even a website [singingsensation](http://singingsensation.co.uk/)

*Sleeping babies* is not a compound term, it is merely an adjective with a noun, and *babies sleeping* is, as you say, a whiz-deletion.

If you avoid *sensation* and substitute a different noun it becomes interchangeable the same as the *babies* example:

> The singing man is a teen heart throb.
>  The man singing is a teen
>   heart throb.